# Angular using string as scope property name in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a project that pulls a number of questions from a JSON file.

The question formats vary but the issue is caused with a slider question type.

I run a HTTP request to get the JSON data and assign it to a scope called 'questions'. I then in the view repeat the questions and if (in this case) the question type is 'slider' I output the HTML.

The issue is that the slider uses a plugin and a scope variable with options. Because I have no control over the questions I am dynamically creating the scopes:

```
angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(question) {
    $scope[question.definedScopeName] = {
        // set up the slider config.
    };
});
```

The JSON question contains a defined name to use for the scope so for this example "sliderOne".

So... in my view I output the slider inside an ng repeat:

```
<rzslider
    class="question__slider"
    rz-slider-model="question.definedScopeName.value"
    rz-slider-options="question.definedScopeName.options">
</rzslider>
```

The issue here is that to set the model scope correctly I am using the data from the questions scope and therefore it is a string.

Anyway I can tell Angular that I actually want to set the model to the scope named $scope.'the defined scope name'.

Thanks!

Comment: your question seems to be a string hence question.<> cannot be done

Comment: @VinodLouis question is an object with a string named "definedScopeName". I want to set the model to the scope variable with the same name

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation with the `this` keyword

```
<!--
<rzslider
    class="question__slider"
    rz-slider-model="question.definedScopeName.value"
    rz-slider-options="question.definedScopeName.options">
</rzslider>
-->

<!-- Use bracket notation -->
<rzslider
    class="question__slider"
    rz-slider-model="this[question.definedScopeName].value"
    rz-slider-options="this[question.definedScopeName].options">
</rzslider>
```

In Angular Expressions, the `this` keyword binds to the scope of the Angular Expression.

Comment: Just when I though this wasn't possible! Thank you very much.